# Recompile apk using original certificate

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool, apksigner

So is it possible to recompile an apk that is decompiled using apktool to use the original certificate or signed with same certificate as it was before decompiled?
Scenario : I decompile an apk with **apktool** and make some changes in it and recompiles using apktool but do not use apk signer instead it signed with its original certificate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can't. To sign the apk with a certain certificate, you need its password and the private info. It's no enough to get the original certificate only by a release apk.

This is the way how Android Apk protect itself from repack and identify the official organization.